# Socket is waiting for client write before writing

Tags: php, apache, sockets, ubuntu, websocket

**Desire:** I want to connect to the socket and have 'running' sent to the client every second.

This of course is a test.

**Issue:** The output 'running' is only sent when the client sends data. It seems like the loop is pausing waiting on the client to write back.

**Code:**

```
$socket = @socket_create_listen("12345");

while (true) {
    $client = socket_accept($socket);
    $msg = "\nHello"."\r\n".chr(0);
    $length = strlen($msg);
    socket_write($client, $msg,$length);
    usleep(5);

    while (true) {
        $msg = 'running'."\r\n".chr(0);
        $length = strlen($msg);
        socket_write($client, $msg, $length);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

**Example:** The code above is in a file on my server. If I run this file and then use telnet to connect to my server on port 12345 `telnet myip# 12345` I expected to see "running" printed in the console every second. Instead "running" is only wrote once. If I type something in the console(ie write data to the server) running is displayed again. Thus running only being sent to the console when I send something to the server.

What could cause this?

Thanks
JT

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the peer code, but if the peer is sending you data, and the send is supposed to control these sends, why aren't you reading it?

Comment: @EJP The peer code? The following above code is in a file on my server. When i run the file I can then connect using telnet from a command prompt...telnet myip# 12345 ...here i want running to be echoed at every second. Im not sure why you claim this is impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server seems fine. The problem is most likely with your client. I tweaked your server and wrote a client that successfully tests against. My tweak was a check that the socket closed. Otherwise, you will get in to a continuous loop.

Here is socketserver.php

```
echo "Starting Server" . "\n\r";
$socket = @socket_create_listen("55000");
while (true) {
    $client = socket_accept($socket);
    $msg = "\nHello"."\r\n".chr(0);
    $length = strlen($msg);
    socket_write($client, $msg,$length);
    usleep(5);

    while (true) {
        $msg = 'running'."\r\n".chr(0);
        $length = strlen($msg);
        $test  = socket_write($client, $msg, $length);
        sleep(1);
        if ($test === false) {
            echo "socket probably closed\n";
            exit;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is socketclient.php

```
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 55000;
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
    exit;
}

echo "\nStarting client";
echo "\nAttempting to connect to '$address' on port '$port'...";
$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $port);
echo "\n\nReading responses...\n\n";
while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
    echo $out;
}

echo "\nClosing socket...";
socket_close($socket);
```

Here is a screenshot of the result.

[image: PHP Client Server Example]

I realize that this is a test, but note that a periodic status server makes far more sense designed using UDP.

Comment: why would you test to see if the socket closed after sleeping?

Comment: @Dan Im hoping to use just raw connection thus not having any client side scripting other then opening then connection to the server.

Comment: @xaxxon I did not close the server. The client did. The check would go better above the send. The check needs to go somewhere or the logic would go in an infinite failure loop after the client disconnects.

Comment: Thanks Worked like a charm! :) idk what i had wrong though but yours works great.

Comment: There's no substantive difference between the two until you get to a disconnect situation.  If you use telnet it still works?  or did you only use the client code provided?

Comment: @xaxxon I used putty and made a raw tcp connection. My error was i had a extra line of code ` $input = trim(socket_read ($client, 256));` This was for some reason causing the error.

Comment: @tman yeah, because I just ran the code you posted, and it works fine with telnet.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using any other client?  nc (netcat) is great for testing things.  Also, put some output in your server to have it log (to screen or file) when it sends data.

I'm guessing your server is working fine but your client is messed up in some way.  Just type `nc <my_ip> 12345` and see what you get.

Remember, telnet is an actual protocol (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854), whereas nc is just straight TCP.

Also, NUL terminating the string may be causing weird issues.  Lose the chr(0) bit and see if that makes it better.

Comment: I added that bit when it wasnt work but I will try a few things and post back! thanks agian

Comment: Looking at the telnet RFC, it seems like NUL is a special character, especially when following carriage return and line feeds.  It's not clear to me exactly what's going on, but I'd definitely lose it, regardless.

Comment: @tman I have to run for a bit.  I'll check on this in a couple hours if you're still having problems.   Also, look at the other answer for how to properly check for a disconnect.  This won't solve the problem you're having now, but it will solve a problem you would have in the future once you solve this one.

Comment: Ok i updated to using a putty which allows for a raw TCP connection. again im only getting data when I pass data to the serber :-/